# RactiveJS doesn't update all vars on set or update

Tags: ractivejs

I have this:

```
{{#config.buildings:building}}
    <div class="building" id="building-item-{{building}}">
        <div class="image-container">
            <div class="thumbnail" style="background: transparent url({{staticUrl}}/game_images/town/buildings/{{building}}/{{building}}-1-thumbnail.png) no-repeat center center;"></div>
            <div class="cover"></div>
            <div class="undercover"></div>

            <div class="level">{{village.buildings[building].level + alreadyInQueue(building)}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="big_title">{{lang('buildings',building)}}</div>
        <p class="{{buildingMaxed(building) ? 'maxed' : ''}}">{{lang('buildings',building+'_description')}}</p>
        <div on-tap="upgradeBuilding:{{building}}" class="upgrade-button" tooltip="{{lang('general','upgrade_building')}}"></div>
        <div on-tap="downgradeBuilding:{{building}}" class="downgrade-button disabled" tooltip="{{lang('general','downgrade_building')}}"></div>
            <div class="resources">
                <div class="resource">
                    <img class="thumbnail" src="{{staticUrl}}/game_images/resources/woodB.png">
                    <label class="res-count-wood">{{config.buildings[building][village.buildings[building].level].wood}}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="resource">
                    <img class="thumbnail" src="{{staticUrl}}/game_images/resources/ironB.png">
                    <label class="res-count-iron">{{config.buildings[building][village.buildings[building].level].clay}}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="resource">
                    <img class="thumbnail" src="{{staticUrl}}/game_images/resources/clayB.png">
                    <label class="res-count-stone">{{config.buildings[building][village.buildings[building].level].iron}}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="resource">
                    <img class="thumbnail" src="{{staticUrl}}/game_images/resources/workersB.png">
                    <label class="res-count-builders">{{config.buildings[building][village.buildings[building].level].people}}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="resource">
                    <img class="thumbnail" src="{{staticUrl}}/game_images/resources/timeB.png">
                    <label class="res-count-time">{{secsToString(config.buildings[building][village.buildings[building].level].time)}}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="hr"></div>
    </div>
{{/config.buildings:building}}
```

When I'm using

```
contentTPL.set('village.buildings[1].level',4)
```

The only things that update are

```
<div class="level">{{village.buildings[building].level + alreadyInQueue(building)}}</div>
// and
<label class="res-count-time">{{secsToString(config.buildings[building][village.buildings[building].level].time)}}</label>
```

I don't seem to understand why the other values don't update on update() as they should. There's no error in the code and I'm using the edge version (same result with the lastest version from 8th of April, 0.4.0).

**UPDATE**
I have stripped all the unnecessary data, and added a console.log in the alreadyQueued function. It gets called on init, but, when i call **contentTPL.update()** it doesn't get called anymore. Nothing updates in the file, when pressing the startQueue button. There's another contentTPL.update() when the queue expires, which updates only the level and the time needed as stated above. I'm asking Rich or Marty to advise on this problem as I'm stuck here for about 4 hours and can't seem to understand wether it is my misuse of the library or it's a bug.

Comment: As far as I can tell it only updates the mustaches which wrap functions in it. But, frankly , I have no idea why. I've updated the post, added new information. I'll try adding an observer instead using update. Will update soon.

Comment: @edduvs It doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong, so it might well be a bug. Any way you can reduce it to a SSCCE in a JSFiddle or similar? Here's a JSFiddle template: http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/va6jU/

Comment: @RichHarris I can't really do that jsFiddle file because the required variables are quite a few. Can I get in touch with you on skype or gtalk or something so I can give you access to the files ? Or some teamviewer ?

Comment: @edduvs unfortunately I'm at work, so that's not possible... would probably need to dig into it in any case. Have you tried deleting chunks of the template until only the problematic parts remain?

Comment: @RichHarris in the last hour I was trying to get that SSCCE working, and I kind of did. It's still quite messy, but here it is, http://jsfiddle.net/va6jU/34/ it is using `contetTPL.update()` which is not working, but if i use detach and reinit `dialogController.load('1',true)` , it works. See for yourself. contentTPL.update() will only update the level as far as you can see, as stated in the initial post.

Comment: @RichHarris and yes, that fiddle is the minimal chunk of code. I stronly believe it is not my code that is wrong. If you want the template in pure html, here it is : http://pastebin.com/nxMKzCWQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a [bug](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/752), which is now [fixed in dev](http://cdn.ractivejs.org/edge/ractive.js).

Comment: The issue is somehow still present, another piece of SSCCE for you. http://jsfiddle.net/va6jU/38/ sorry for troubling you.